# how can you use an AJAX GET request to display fetched stdclass Objects

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, pdo

I've successfully used `PDO` to fetch data from my database, using the `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` method, and the query returns this:

```
Array (
       [0] => stdClass Object
       (
        [id] => 2
        [title] => Johnny Sims
        [img] => 
        [description] => 
        [school] => 
        [location] => 1
        [url] => 
        [tablename] => 2
        [votes] => 5
        [name] => President Candidates
        [Numopinions] => 6
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 2
        [title] => Jeremy Pinto
        [img] => 
        [description] => 
        [school] => 
        [location] => 1
        [url] => 
        [tablename] => 2
        [votes] => 4
        [name] => Presidential Candidates
        [Numopinions] => 6
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 2
        [title] => Sarah Bushels
        [img] => 
        [description] => 
        [school] => 
        [location] => 1
        [url] => 
        [tablename] => 2
        [votes] => 3
        [name] => Presidential Candidates
        [Numopinions] => 6
    )
    )
```

How would one use an `AJAX` `GET` request to interact with this data if this is what is echoed?

Comment: You would access it the same way you would access it without `AJAX`. What do you mean?

Comment: The only think you would probably need to do differently is `echo` using `jSON` encoding.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to interact with it in JavaScript, in which case you can `json_encode($array)` it then output it to a page with content-type header set to application/json.

If you then request that page with AJAX and load the result into a var it will automatically parse to a JavaScript array.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a representation of your scenario.

index.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var userId= 1; //this can be anything like a gobal variable or an user input, etc
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax.php",
            type: "GET",
            data: {id : userId}, //userId is the variable that you are going to pass to ajax.php
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                //your logic what do you want to do with it
                $("#result").html( data.title + '-' + data.name);
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
            }
        })
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

ajax.php

```
<?php
//you logic here, this is just a dumy example

$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : 0;
$db_records = array(
    array(
        "id" => 2,
        "title" => 'Jeremy Pinto',
        "img" => '',
        "description" => '',
        "school" => '',
        "location" => 1,
        "url" => '',
        "tablename" => 2,
        "votes" => 4,
        "name" => 'Presidential Candidates',
        "Numopinions" => 6
    ),

    array (
        "id" => 2,
        "title" => 'Sarah Bushels',
        "img" => '',
        "description" => '',
        "school" => '',
        "location" => 1,
        "url" => '',
        "tablename" => 2,
        "votes" => 3,
        "name" => 'Presidential Candidates',
        "Numopinions" => 6
    )
);

print json_encode($db_records[$id]);
```